# Не отображается динамическое содержимое в thymeleaf spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Не отображается динамическое содержимое, которое я передаю через thymeleaf на всех страницах, кроме одной. Отображается только show.html

Код моего контроллера:

```java
package org.estimilian.HopNScotch.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.estimilian.HopNScotch.dao.TeacherDAO;
import org.estimilian.HopNScotch.models.Teacher;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/teachers")
public class TeachersController {

    private final TeacherDAO teacherDAO;

    @Autowired
    public TeachersController(TeacherDAO teacherDAO) {
        this.teacherDAO = teacherDAO;
    }


    @GetMapping()
    public String index(Model model) {
        // Получим всех людей из DAO и передадим на отображение в представление
        model.addAttribute("teachers", teacherDAO.index());
        return "teachers/index";
    }
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String show(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        // Получим одного человека по id из DAO и передадим отображение в представление
        model.addAttribute("teacher", teacherDAO.show(id));
        return "teachers/show";
    }
    @GetMapping("/new")
    public String newTeacher(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("teacher", new Teacher());
        return "teachers/new";
    }
    @PostMapping()
    public String create(@ModelAttribute("teacher") @Valid Teacher teacher, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) return "teachers/new";
        teacherDAO.save(teacher);
        return "redirect:/teachers";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}/edit")
    public String edit(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
        model.addAttribute("teacher", teacherDAO.show(id));
        return "teachers/edit";
    }

    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public String  update(@ModelAttribute("teacher") @Valid Teacher teacher, BindingResult bindingResult,
                          @PathVariable("id") int id) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) return "teachers/edit";
        teacherDAO.update(id, teacher);
        return "redirect:/teachers";
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public String  delete(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        teacherDAO.delete(id);
        return "redirect:/teachers";
    }
}
```

Код моего DAO

```java
package org.estimilian.HopNScotch.dao;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.estimilian.HopNScotch.models.Teacher;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class TeacherDAO {
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public TeacherDAO(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public List<Teacher> index() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM teachers", new TeacherMapper());
    }

    public Teacher show(int id) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE id=?", new Object[]{id}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Teacher.class))
                .stream().findAny().orElse(null);
    }

    public void save(Teacher teacher) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO teachers(lastname, firstname, patronymic, sex, dateOfBirth, maxLanguageLvl," +
                        "experienceOfNotStandatProjects, nearestSubway, workLoad) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                teacher.getLastName(), teacher.getFirstName(), teacher.getPatronymic(),teacher.getSex(),
                teacher.getDateOfBirth(), teacher.getMaxLanguageLvl(), teacher.getExperienceOfNotStandardProjects(),
                teacher.getNearestSubway(), teacher.getWorkLoad());
    }
      //@TODO исправить в 2 местах Standat на Standard как только в таблице будет исправлено
    public void update(int id, Teacher teacher) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE teachers SET lastname=?, firstname=?, patronymic=?, sex=?, dateOfBirth=?, maxLanguageLvl=?, " +
                        "experienceOfNotStandatProjects=?, nearestSubway=?, workLoad=? WHERE id=?",
                teacher.getLastName(), teacher.getFirstName(), teacher.getPatronymic(),teacher.getSex(),
                teacher.getDateOfBirth(), teacher.getMaxLanguageLvl(), teacher.getExperienceOfNotStandardProjects(),
                teacher.getNearestSubway(), teacher.getWorkLoad(), id);
    }
    public void delete(int id) {
        jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM teachers WHERE id=?", id);
    }

}
```

Код одной из страниц, которая не отображается - index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Teachers</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div th:each="teacher : ${teachers}">
        <a th:href="@{/teachers/{id}(id=${teacher.value.getId()})}"
           th:text="${teacher.value.getLastName() + teacher.value.getFirstName() + ', ' + teacher.value.getWorkLoad() + ' hours workload'}"> user </a>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    <a href="/teachers/new">Create new teacher</a>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Код другой страницы, где отображается только текст "Lastname:" и все

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>New teacher</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/teachers}" th:object="${teacher}" >
        <label for="lastname">Lastname: </label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{lastname}" id="lastname"/>
        <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastname')}" th:errors="*{lastname}">Lastname error</div>
        <br/>
        <label for="firstname">Firstname: </label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{firstname}" id="firstname"/>
        <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstname')}" th:errors="*{firstname}">Firstname error</div>
        <br/>
        <label for="patronymic">Patronymic: </label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{patronymic}" id="patronymic"/>
        <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('patronymic')}" th:errors="*{patronymic}">Patronymic error</div>
        <br/>
        <label for="sex">SEX: </label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{sex}" id="sex"/>
        <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('sex')}" th:errors="*{sex}">sex error</div>
        <br/>
        <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of birth: </label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{dateOfBirth}" id="dateOfBirth"/>
        <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('dateOfBirth')}" th:errors="*{dateOfBirth}">dateOfBirth error</div>
        <br/>
        <label for="maxLanguageLvl">Max language level: </label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{maxLanguageLvl}" id="maxLanguageLvl"/>
        <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('maxLanguageLvl')}" th:errors="*{maxLanguageLvl}">maxLanguageLvl error</div>
        <br/>
        <label for="experienceOfNotStandardProjects">Experience of not standard projects: </label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{experienceOfNotStandardProjects}"        id="experienceOfNotStandardProjects"/>
        <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('experienceOfNotStandardProjects')}" th:errors="*{experienceOfNotStandardProjects}">experienceOfNotStandardProjects error</div>
        <br/>
        <label for="nearestSubway">Nearest subway station: </label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{nearestSubway}" id="nearestSubway"/>
        <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nearestSubway')}" th:errors="*{nearestSubway}">nearestSubway error</div>
        <br/>
        <label for="workload">Workload: </label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{workload}" id="workload"/>
        <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('workload')}" th:errors="*{workload}">workload error</div>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Add teacher"/>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Код show.html - единственной страницы, которая отображается (правда есть проблемы с кодировкой, но тут я уже разберусь наверное)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Teacher</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p th:text="${teacher.getLastName()}">VALUE </p>
    <p th:text="${teacher.getFirstName()}">VALUE </p>
    <p th:text="${teacher.getId()}">VALUE </p>

    <a th:href="@{/teachers/{id}/edit(id=${teacher.getId()})}">Edit</a>
    <br/>
    <form th:method="DELETE" th:action="@{/teachers/{id}(id=${teacher.getId()})}">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```